# When i try trigger ngbpopover on click on icon but it is not trigger

Tags: angular

let tmplout = '';
tmplout += '' + this.widgetData.title;

```
            if (this.widgetData.description || this.widgetData.timecolumn) {
                // tmplout += ' <i title="' + this.widgetData.description + '"class="fa-light fa-square-info"></i>';
                tmplout += '<i class="fa-light fa-square-info m-l-5" triggers="click" container="body" [autoClose]="true" [ngbPopover]="popContent" [popoverTitle]="popTitle"></i>';
                tmplout += '<ng-template #popContent>' + this.widgetData.description;
                if (this.widgetData.timecolumn) {
                    tmplout += '<br />';
                    tmplout += 'Column for Time filtering:';
                    tmplout += '<b>' + this.widgetData.timecolumn;
                    tmplout += '</b>';
                }
                tmplout += '</ng-template>';
            }

            tmplout += '</h4></h1></div>';
            tmplout += '<h3 class="text-colorF">';
            tmplout += '</h3>';
            this.widgetData.tploutput = tmplout;
```

Popover property is not setting properly in tmplout += ' <i title="' + this.widgetData.description + '"class="fa-light fa-square-info">'; this is the issue